# Function invocation inside curly braces {}

Tags: javascript, function, curly-braces, function-invocation

I am trying to implement an online chat using one of the main providers. They advised me to embed a code looking like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function embedScriptInsideHTMLtags() {
    // responsible code
  }
  {
    embedScriptInsideHTMLtags();
  }
</script>
```

My question is, what is the difference between the above and the below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function embedScriptInsideHTMLtags() {
    // responsible code
  }  
  embedScriptInsideHTMLtags();
</script>
```

Comment: Nothing really.

Answer (score 2):

The first example is using what's called a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block). In this case there is no difference in the two examples. Per the MDN link:

> Variables declared with var or created by function declarations in non-strict mode **do not** have block scope. Variables introduced within a block are scoped to the containing function or script, and the effects of setting them persist beyond the block itself. In other words, block statements do not introduce a scope.

But in *strict mode*

> identifiers declared with let and const do have block scope

and

> In strict mode, starting with ES2015, functions inside blocks are scoped to that block. Prior to ES2015, block-level functions were forbidden in strict mode.

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand the difference between accessing a var outside block and accessing let and const outside block one is possible(var) other is not.

Your code does not have any difference but

```
<script>
  function embedScriptInsideHTMLtags() {
    // responsible code
    return 'something';
  }
  {
    const b=embedScriptInsideHTMLtags();
  }
  const c= embedScriptInsideHTMLtags();
</script>
```

Here you can access c from the outside or other scripts but b won't be accessible. In your case if you are just calling a function then it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already answered your specific question, but I also wanted to point out that the W3C now recommends you omit the type attribute from JS `<script>` tags, and has since the HTML5 specification came out years ago. The specification encourages developers to not use a redundant MIME type in tags, as `text/javascript` is. When you use a script tag that will contain JavaScript code, you  can merely write `<script>` without any attributes. You can read about it from the [MDN documentation for the script tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-type)

Similarly, when using the `<link>` tag for a stylesheet (with `rel="stylesheet`, you no longer need to use `type="text/css"`. Since CSS is the only type of stylesheet available on the web, the type attribute for stylesheets is now redundant. You can read more about that from the [MDN documentation for the link tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-type).

Comment: Thank you for this I changed my answer accordingly.